# ./RFSniffer failes on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, radio

I`m trying to send a message over 433MHz with my raspberry pi

[Link to hardware](https://www.amazon.de/receiver-Superregeneration-Wireless-Transmitter-Burglar/dp/B00ATZV5EQ)

Sender and Receiver are connected. Here is a Link to the tutorial I used to connect sender and receiver ([Link](http://pygmalion.nitri.de/remote-controlled-mains-sockets-with-raspberry-pi-561.html))

**wiring pi** is installed and I installed **433Utils (Ninjablock)** with [this](http://www.princetronics.com/how-to-read-433-mhz-codes-w-raspberry-pi-433-mhz-receiver/) tutorial.

In short:

```
cd ~/
git clone git://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils.git
cd 433Utils/RPi_utils
make
```

Simple problem .... it doesn't work.
when using `sudo ./RFSniffer` CPU usage goes up to 99/100% but nothing happens. I am using different 433 MHz remotes (brennenstuhl and cheap china products) but I can't catch a signal.(Just to be clear: Start`sudo ./RFSniffer` and press different buttons on my different remotes next to the 433 Mhz receiver)

I don't think it's a hardware problem because I tried **pilight** and everything works fine. ([Link](https://www.pilight.org)

So my Problem is that the **433Utils** software from **ninjablocks** does not work.
Could this be because of the Pi version (3)?

Comment: How close to the receiver is the remote?

Comment: Very close. 5cm. It worked with pilight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is just too much radio noise.

Try my implementation at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D

It should use a lot less CPU.

It requires [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) which may already be installed if you are using a recent Raspbian.

Comment: I'll try but I don't think it has something to do with too much radio noise, since the whole setup works with **pilight** I'll try your implementation

Comment: Thanks a lot.... This works like a charm. 5,6% CPU Usage :-) I'll recommend PIGPIO from now on :-) It's a shame that PIGPIO  doesn't show up when I google raspberry pi and 433

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the 433Utils if it doesn't recognize the protocol. You could try my toolkit which might help. [Home Automation with 433MHz rf Nexa Sockets and the Blyss Wireless Doorbell](https://danicymru.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/433mhz-rf-nexa-sockets-and-the-blyss-wireless-doorbell/)